# Help understand theorem that any set of first order sentences satisfied by N has a model that's a strict superset of N.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, first-order-logic, meta-math

I saw the following theorem (in Computational Complexity book by Papadimitriou, p. 111) :

> Theorem :
>
> If $\Delta$ is a set of first-order sentences such that $N$
> $\vDash \Delta$, then there is a model $N'$ such that $N' \vDash$
> $\Delta$, and the universe of $N'$ is a proper superset of the universe
> of $N$.
>
> Proof :
>
> Consider the sentences $\phi_i$ = $\exists x ((x!=0) \wedge$
> $(x!=1)\  \wedge ... (x!=i))$, and the set $\Delta \cup \{\phi_i:$
> $i>=0\}$. The set is consistent, because if it were not, if would have
> a finite subset that is inconsistent. This finite subset contains only
> finitely many of the $\phi_i$ sentences. But $N$ obviously satisfies
> both $\Delta$ and any finite subset of these sentences. So, there is a
> model of $\Delta \cup \{\phi_i: i>=0\}$, *and the universe of this
> model must be a strict superset of the universe of $N$*.

My first question is about the last (italicized) statement of the proof above : Why must the universe of the model be a superset of $N$? Any individual sentence $\phi_i$ can be satisfied by $N$ itself (just choose x=i+1, for example), and so $N$ simultaneously satisfies all $\phi_i$, and therefore $N$ is a model for $\Delta \cup \{\phi_i: i>=0\}$.

Second, the book claims that this theorem "shows that the nonstandard model $N'$ of number theory (the natural numbers plus a disjoint copy of the integers) cannot be differentiated from $N$ by first-order sentences." But all this theorem claims to show is that for any set of first orders sentences $\Delta$ there is *some* strict superset of $N$ that statisfies $\Delta$. How do we know that the nonstandard model $N'$ (with the disjoint copy of the integers) is one such superset?

Comment: The proof in  your quotation from the book is certainly wrong. $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies each sentence $\phi_i$. $\phi_i$ should say something like $c > i$ where $c$ is a new constant symbol. Then each $\phi_i$ is talking about  the same witness $c$ and a model of the $\phi_i$ must contain an element $c$ that is greater than every natural number. (The description of a non-standard model as the natural numbers plus a copy of the integers is also incorrect.)

Comment: What about the second claim - that N' (natural numbers plus a disjoint copy of the integers) cannot be differentiated from N by first order sentences? How can we prove that?

(Regarding N' being the description of non-standard model - it wasn't meant in the book that this is the only non-standard model, it was just an example of one)

Comment: The two models satisfy exactly the same set of first-order sentences, so no first-order sentence can distinguish between them.  (The point of the part of my comment in parentheses is that a non-standard model of arithmetic is necessarily more intricate than the natural numbers plus a copy of the integers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, the proof doesn't work in the form you have quoted it. What the proof *tries to be* is known as the **usual compactness argument** for nonstandard models of arithmetic, but it botches the details.

How it is supposed to go is something like this:

1. First we *extend the language of arithmetic* with a new constant symbol $c$.
2. Then consider the theory whose axioms are (a) the sentences $\Delta$, (b) the infinitely many *new* axioms $c\ne 0, c\ne 1, c\ne 2, \ldots$, (c) if necessary, sufficiently many axioms to guarantee that $0, 1, 2,\ldots$ are all distinct and arithmetic on them gives the correct results.
3. Any *finite* subset of the new theory has a model, namely $\mathbb N$ with $c$ assigned to some number whose new axiom is not in the finite subset.
4. Therefore, by compactness, there is a model for the *entire* new theory. If we forget the part of the model that interprets the new constant $c$ we get a model for $\Delta$. However, because the new model has to contain an interpretation of $c$, it needs to contain at least one element that is not one of $0, 1, 2, \ldots$. Thus, its domain can be identified with a superset of $\mathbb N$.

If the $N$ in your quote is not necessarily $\mathbb N$, but simply some model of $\Delta$, then a few technical changes to this scheme are necessary -- the new theory must contain new constants for each element of the domain of $N$, and axioms that say these elements are distinct and behave like they do in $N$. This will make sure that the new model contains an isomorphic copy of $N$.

Where the quoted proof goes wrong is that it attempts to replace the new constant $c$ with a separately quantified variable for each new axiom. But that doesn't work; it will not force the new model to have *the same* witness for each of the new axioms, and therefore its new theory may just be $\mathbb N$ itself.

Finally, it is simply **wrong** that the nonstandard model consists of "the natural numbers plus a disjoint copy of the integers". That is one possible nonstandard model of just zero and the successor function, but as soon as one wants to handle addition and multiplication too, nonstandard models will necessarily have an extremely complex structure -- in fact, one that cannot even be *described* in a computable way.

Comment: Thanks Henning. The only reason I was messing around trying to say the same things in comments was that I don't have Papadimitiriou's book to hand (and I am rather surprised to think that such a well-known book contains such drivel).

Comment: @RobArthan: I don't have the book either, hence my hedging about "in the quoted form".

Comment: @RobArthan: Here's a scan of the page I quoted : http://i.imgur.com/z171iIQ.png  and here's a scan of the part in section 5.2 where it defines N' http://i.imgur.com/BDrLKsd.png  (the bottom paragraph).

Comment: @HenningMakholm : Thank you for your answer! About what you said in the last paragraph on the inability to even describe the nonstandard model - what do you mean by "describe"? In the proof you gave above, the model M' for the new (extended) theory will contain at least one element that is not in N or any isomorphic copy of it. So M' is not a standard model of number theory, and yet you have just characterized (described) it  - as the model that satisfies the extended theory (Δ∪{ϕi}).

Comment: @Tim - I think that what Henning was getting at is a corollary of Tennebaum's theorem: every recursive model of PA is isomorphic to the standard model. Therefore, in most non-standard models addition and multiplication won't behave recursively, which is why we can't describe them in a computable way.

Comment: Yes, what @Nagase said. The model can't be described as "the model that satisfies the extended theory", because the extended theory will in general have many _non-isomorphic_ models. One might try with "the model that results from applying Henkin's proof of the completeness theorem to the extended theory" -- but that isn't worth much as a description because that proof is fundamentally non-constructive (even though it is formally deterministic).